# Play Framework errors out when an attempt to create an aws ec2 Client is made

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, playframework-2.0, ec2-api-tools

I am trying to make a simple play framework application which monitors my aws ec2 instances. I have been following [this guide](http://www.kpbird.com/2013/09/aws-sdk-for-java-tutorial-2-ec2.html) to get started. This is the method I am having trouble with.

```
public static AmazonEC2Client createClient(){
    String accessKey = "ACCESS_KEY";
    String secretKey = "SECRET_KEY";
    String endpoint = "ec2.us-east-1.amazonaws.com";

    BasicAWSCredentials credentials  = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);
    AmazonEC2Client ec2Client = new AmazonEC2Client(credentials);
    ec2Client.setEndpoint(endpoint);
    return ec2Client;
}
```

When the method runs I get this error and the play server stops.

```
Uncaught error from thread [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] shutting down JVM since       'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[play]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeSocketFactory
at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.<init>(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:66)
at com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client.<init>(AmazonEC2Client.java:151)
at com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client.<init>(AmazonEC2Client.java:132)
at models.AwsServer.createClient(AwsServer.java:17)
at controllers.Devices.index(Devices.java:11)
at     Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(routes_routing.scala:61)
at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(routes_routing.scala:61)
at play.core.Router$HandlerInvoker$$anon$7$$anon$2.invocation(Router.scala:183)
at play.core.Router$Routes$$anon$1.invocation(Router.scala:377)
at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$1.call(JavaAction.scala:56)
at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$3.apply(JavaAction.scala:91)
at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$3.apply(JavaAction.scala:90)
at play.core.j.FPromiseHelper$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(FPromiseHelper.scala:82)
at play.core.j.FPromiseHelper$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(FPromiseHelper.scala:82)
at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:278)
at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:274)
at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:29)
[ERROR] [10/01/2013 14:20:16.319] [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [ActorSystem(play)] Uncaught error from thread [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeSocketFactory
at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.<init>(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:66)
at com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client.<init>(AmazonEC2Client.java:151)
at com.amazonaws.services.ec2.AmazonEC2Client.<init>(AmazonEC2Client.java:132)
at models.AwsServer.createClient(AwsServer.java:17)
at controllers.Devices.index(Devices.java:11)
at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(routes_routing.scala:61)
at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(routes_routing.scala:61)
at play.core.Router$HandlerInvoker$$anon$7$$anon$2.invocation(Router.scala:183)
at play.core.Router$Routes$$anon$1.invocation(Router.scala:377)
at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$1.call(JavaAction.scala:56)
at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$3.apply(JavaAction.scala:91)
at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$3.apply(JavaAction.scala:90)
at play.core.j.FPromiseHelper$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(FPromiseHelper.scala:82)
at play.core.j.FPromiseHelper$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(FPromiseHelper.scala:82)
at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:278)
at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:274)
at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:29)
at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext$$anon$2.run(HttpExecutionContext.scala:37)
at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:42)
at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeSocketFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
... 24 more
at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext$$anon$2.run(HttpExecutionContext.scala:37)

at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:42)
at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.conn.scheme.SchemeSocketFactory
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
... 24 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error. I changed the version of my maven dependency and that solved the error.

New Dependency:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Old dependency:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Also, make sure you remove the old version from your classpath, as it tends to pick up the latest version if you do not do that. Hope this helps :)

Comment: the following one works too
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.002</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: I will test this as soon as I get a chance.